# DBSCAN on textual and numerical columns

Tags: clustering, word-embeddings, categorical-data, dbscan, doc2vec

I have a dataset which has two columns:

```
title      price
sentence1  12
sentence2  13
```

I have used `doc2vec` to convert the sentences into vectors of size 100 as below:

```
LabeledSentence1 = gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument

all_content = []
j=0

for title in query_result['title_clean'].values:
    all_content.append(LabeledSentence1(title,[j]))
    j+=1
print("Number of texts processed: ", j)

cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

d2v_model = Doc2Vec(dm=1, vector_size=100, negative=5, hs=0, 
min_count=2, sample = 0, workers=cores, alpha=0.025, 
min_alpha=0.001)

d2v_model.build_vocab([x for x in tqdm(all_content)])

all_content  = utils.shuffle(all_content)

d2v_model.train(all_content,total_examples=len(all_content), epochs=30)
```

So `d2v_model.docvecs.doctag_syn0` returns me vectors of all the sentences

I want to now perform clustering using DBSCAN but since I have the other price column which is numeric I am having some trouble fitting the final data to the model. I have a similar problem as described in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52507815/clustering-data-that-has-both-text-and-numeric-value), one of my columns has an array of 100 sizes each row, and the other column is just numeric. Hence when I perform dbscan on the data I get the same error.

Is there any smart way to handle such cases? Combining doc2vec output with other numerical columns to prepare it for clustering? Something like this, where `both_numeric_categical_columns` is the desired input to the model:

```
clf = DBSCAN(eps=0.5, min_samples=10)
X = clf.fit(both_numeric_categical_columns)
labels=clf.labels_.tolist()

cluster1 = query_result_mini.copy()

cluster1['clusters'] = clf.fit_predict(both_numeric_categical_columns)
```

Comment: DBScan is a distance-based clustering technique. The problem with concatenating both variables is how do you normalise the price value. It may be that you just add the features together and it works. A more safe way, in my opinion, could be to do some feature extraction on the sentence embeddings (e.g., PCA) and use its output with the price using a Hierarchical clustering.

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention which package you are using. If you using scikit-learn,
[`sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html) concatenates results of multiple transformer objects.

Something like this:

```py
from sklearn.cluster             import DBSCAN
from sklearn.pipeline            import FeatureUnion, Pipeline
from skearnsklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

pipeline = Pipeline([('feats', FeatureUnion([
                        ('doc2vec', d2v_model,        ['sentence1', 'sentence2']), 
                        ('numeric', StandardScaler(), ['price']) 
                    ])),
                    ('cluster', DBSCAN())  
                    ])
```